# Gatsby, problem with javascript not loading until refreshing page

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I am running into an issue with getting SimpleLightbox not loading for me until I refresh the page on my Gatsby site. I have a demo up where if you go from the "inspirations" page (https://effulgent-liger-a1d01e.netlify.app/inspiration) then click on an individual inspiration you will see by clicking on the photo in the gallery that it just opens the photo url and not the lightbox. Then if you refresh the page and click an image in the gallery it then loads the lightbox fine. I assume this is part of my Gatsby learning process, but stumped on this. Thanks for any help.

Here is my individual "inspiration" post file code.

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { GatsbyImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image'
import SimpleLightbox from 'simple-lightbox'

import 'simple-lightbox/dist/simpleLightbox.min.css'

import Seo from "../components/seo"
import CTAOne from '../components/ctaOne'

const HeroSection = styled.section`
  height: 650px;
  position: relative;

  @media(min-width: 768px) {
    height: 825px;
  }

  .hero-image .gatsby-image-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 650px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;

    @media(min-width: 768px) {
      height: 825px;
    }
  }

  .hero-content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    max-width: 1160px;
    padding: 15px 0;
    background-color: var(--white-trans);

    .hero-border-top,
    .hero-border-bottom {
      height: 18px;
      width: 100%;
      border: 6px solid var(--white-trans);
    }

    .hero-border-top {
      margin-top: -33px;
    }

    .hero-border-bottom {
      margin-bottom: -33px;
    }

    h1 {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    p {
      font-size: 21px;
      line-height: 1.2;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 900px;
      margin: 25px auto 21px auto;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right: 10px;

      @media(min-width: 768px) {
        font-size: 23px;
      }
    }
  }
`

const InspirationPostContainer = styled.section`
  margin-bottom: 90px;

  .inspiration-desc {
    max-width: 850px;
    margin: 90px auto 85px auto;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .inspiration-grid {
    column-count: 1;
    column-gap: 55px;

    @media(min-width: 640px) {
      column-count: 2;
    }

    @media(min-width: 992px) {
      column-count: 3;
    }
  }

  .item {
    margin: 0 0 40px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
    break-inside: avoid;
  }

  .item > img {
    grid-row: 1 / -1;
    grid-column: 1;
  }
`

function InspirationPost({ pageContext }) {
  const { inspiration } = pageContext

  if (typeof window !== `undefined`) {
    new SimpleLightbox({elements: '.inspiration-grid a'})
  }

  return (
    <>
      <HeroSection>
          <div className='hero-image'>
            <GatsbyImage image={inspiration.inspiration.projectFeaturedPhoto.gatsbyImage} alt={inspiration.inspiration.projectFeaturedPhoto.altText} />
          </div>
          <div className="hero-content">
            <div className='hero-border-top'></div>
            <h1>{inspiration.inspiration.projectTitle}</h1>
            <div className='hero-border-bottom'></div>
          </div>
      </HeroSection>
      <InspirationPostContainer>
        <div className="container">
          <div className='inspiration-desc'>{inspiration.inspiration.projectDescription}</div>
          <h2>Project Gallery</h2>
          <div className='inspiration-grid'>
            {inspiration.inspiration.projectGallery.map((node) => (
              <a href={`${node.mediaItemUrl}`} className='item' key={node.id}>
                <GatsbyImage image={node.gatsbyImage} alt={node.altText} />
              </a>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </InspirationPostContainer>
      <CTAOne />
    </>
  )
}

export default InspirationPost
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to the SimpleLightbox module. Have you tried something like this?

```
  useEffect(()=>{
     if (typeof window !== `undefined`) {
       new SimpleLightbox({elements: '.inspiration-grid a'})
     }
   },[])
```

It looks like the library is not loaded at the first initial render or the elements are not ready at the same time that the lightbox is requesting them, but when hydration occurs, everything works as it should, so loading it at the right time or forcing a reload should work.